# Convert nested json to html

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I've been given the task of taking a json object(it will not be this one, could be more or less nested and content) and writing a function that will parse it out and append it to a html page.  Specifically they will give me a file that looks like this that I will have to take the data from.  It could be one level deep or 15 levels deep.  I just dont know where to begin.  I know I should either use recursion r a while loop but past that im completely lost.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be helpful, thanks.

```
    [
  {
    "tag": "section",
    "content": {
      "tag": "h2",
      "content": "Welcome to My Page!"
    }
  },
  {
    "tag": "section",
    "content": [
      {
        "tag": "h3",
        "content": "My Favorite Things"
      },
      {
        "tag": "ul",
        "content": [
          {
            "tag": "li",
            "content": "<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/200'/>"
          },
          {
            "tag": "li",
            "content": "<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/201/200'/>"
          },
          {
            "tag": "li",
            "content": "<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/201'/>"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tag": "p",
        "content": [
          {
            "tag": "span",
            "content": "In short, I "
          },
          {
            "tag": "strong",
            "content": "just love"
          },
          {
            "tag": "span",
            "content": " kittens!"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Since it is structured, recursion a pretty good idea.

Comment: Here's a pointer: Start with one level of object, forget the nesting. Write a tiny function that converts the smallest logical unit of your structure above into the appropriate HTML element. No loops, no anything. Add that function to your question. Continue to think about how to re-use that function to convert lists of items to lists of HTML elements. Once you have a function that can convert a list, continue to think about how to write a third function that convert lists of lists.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but ive only done basic example recursion problems before.  I only have a day to get this figured out and I dont know if I might be in over my head with this one.

Comment: @DerekW seriously - there are frameworks out there to make this an easy problem - you do not have to worry about recursion and finding clever ways to solve this. It's straight forward - I'm posting answer below.

Comment: @Tomalak I just got it done.  Just did it one small piece at a time and kept adding complexity to the input and then reworking my code to handle it.  thanks for the advice.

Comment: That's good to hear. :) It's not often that people listen to advice that does not contain copyable code, you can be proud of that!

Answer (score 4):

Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/ej4ftzcs/

```
// A recursive function to build DOM tree from a json structure
function buildTree(tree, container) {  
  tree.forEach(function(node) {

    var el = document.createElement(node.tag);

    if (Array.isArray(node.content)) {
        buildTree(node.content, el);
    } 
    else if (typeof(node.content) == 'object') {
        buildTree([node.content], el);
    }
    else {
        el.innerHTML = node.content;
    }

    container.appendChild(el);
  });
}

// Run !!!
buildTree(tree, document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I almost have it done a similar, but much messier way.

Comment: @DerekW can i ask why you didn't adopt the template framework way? It's not messy at all and way easier with less code and less buggy - a framework written specifically for the purpose of building html from json is surely better than doing something messy from scratch?

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck I didnt want to use a framework for this because doing this without a framework was a much bigger learning experience for me.  Thanks for the help!  Got it done, and while its super messy, I know I can go back and rewrite it much better now that I have the logic figured out.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a template framework. There are many out there and some are good if the user needs to be able to edit the values and some are great (easy to use) if you only need to display your data (one way binding).

Personally i'd use a framework like Angular ([Angular1](https://angularjs.org/) or [Angular2](https://angular.io/)) since they are complete framework and can help you with a lot of stuff. That said, both might be overkill, especially if you're not familiar with them and only need to create some html from the json.

**The simpler solution would be to use a template system like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/#demo) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Both are great template systems - the latter builing on top of the other.**

Good luck - I'm sure it's going to be fun and somewhat easier than you're fearing. Since you mentioned recursion, yes use that, but let the frameworks do it for you - less trouble and less error prone :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `document.createElement("tag");` function to create an element in your memory (`var element = document.createElement(currentLevel.tag);`)
Than you can use `element.appendChild(otherelement);` to put something inside of it.
You can check what is the "content"s type (string or array) by checking if `typeof currentLevel.content` is "object" or "string".

When it comes writing it down, than just get the element you want it in and `targetElement.appendChild(element);` it inside.
If you however want just the html code, than
`var HTMLcode = element.outerHTML;`